Apigee Oauthv2 policy with third-party auth server
Recently I'm using a lot Google Apigee. For a project we're working we need to implement an Apigee proxy where the consumers can execute graphql queries.
For security concerns we want to add a third party federation with our SSO company provider.
So the question is: Can I use Oauthv2 policy for authorization code flow in that case? Because it seems are fine just for usecase where Apigee is the authorization server.
I would like to avoid build all the flow in Apigee manually.
Thanks
I saw that Oauthv2 policy has done operations like generateAuthorizationCode but seems it doesn't work.
